# Can't apply wpf material design icon to button

Tags: wpf, material-design-in-xaml

It is trivial what I am trying to do, but am I am kind of new to WPF and I am missing something.

I have a grid

```
 <Grid x:Name="statusBarGrid" Background="{Binding}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <materialDesign:PackIcon x:Name="statusBarIcon" Kind="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{Binding}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlockMessage" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button x:Name="buttonCloseMessage" Content="{materialDesign:PackIcon SmileyHappy}" ToolTip="Icon"  Grid.Column="2"/>
 </Grid>
```

Based on [MaterialDesignInXamlGit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Icons)  this is the way to apply an icon to a button

```
<Button Name="BtnIcon" Content="{materialDesign:PackIcon SmileyHappy}"
        ToolTip="Icon"/>
```

So what am I missing? Because my button is blue and has no icon inside it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine for me. I believe that some other `Style` is overriding your `Button`. Can you try setting your `Style` locally and try. Like,

```xml
<Button x:Name="buttonCloseMessage" ToolTip="Icon" Grid.Column="2">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{materialDesign:PackIcon SmileyHappy}"/>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, I will try and look for what ever overrides the style of my button. It is strange, as this is a user control that is placed in an other grid that has no style. There is blue in the hole application. Thank you for the solution

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
`<Button Content="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=SmileyHappy}"`